# random graph's #edges based on probability

Tags: probability, graphing-functions

If probability of occurrence of edges is 1/2, then will there be n c 2 * (1/2) total edges. Does this applies irrespective of where edges do occur.

Comment: What do you mean by "where edges do occur"?

Comment: where means "between any two edges"

Comment: sorry, "between any two vertices"

Answer (score 1):

If the probability of occurrence of every edge in $K_n$ is $1/2$, the *expected* number of edges is indeed $\frac12 \binom{n}{2}$. The actual number will vary between samples. The number of edges  is a random variable that follows the [binomial distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution).

Answer (score 1):

In an Erdos-Renyi random graph, the probability of an edge occurring between any two vertices is denoted by $p$. In your case $p=1/2$. Moreover, each edge occurs independently from another. In essence each edge is determined by an independent coin flip with bias $p$. That means the probability of having exactly $k$ edges in your graph is binomial: $\binom{\binom{n}{2}}{k}p^k(1-p)^{\binom{n}{2}-k}$. The *expected number* of edges is thus $p\binom{n}{2}$ which in your case is $\frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{2}$. That means if you have a graph with $n$ vertices, and you draw an Erdos Renyi random graph on them, and then repeat this experiment a bunch of times, the average number number of edges you will see is $\frac{1}{2}\binom{n}{2}$.